# Unable to get permission to notify. FirebaseError: Error shows before choosing notification prompt

Tags: javascript, laravel, firebase, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

Unable to get permission to notify. FirebaseError: Messaging: The required permissions were not granted and dismissed instead. (messaging/permission-default). shows on the console before i can even choose an option from notification prompt. Normally this error is supposed to show after selecting an option from the notification prompt but for some reason it shows before i can even click the prompt and thus the notification is not working now. although it has been working flawlessly before now. This code currently works well on chrome Version 81.0.4044.113 (Official Build) (64-bit) , it has been working well on firefox 44 before now.

```
 if (!("Notification" in window)) {
console.error("Notification isn't enabled");
} else if (Notification.permission === "granted") {
console.log("Notification is enabled");
 } else if (Notification.permission !== "denied") {

 // Retrieve an instance of Firebase Messaging so that it can handle background
  // messages.
 firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  const messaging = firebase.messaging();
  messaging
  .requestPermission()
  .then(function () {
   // MsgElem.innerHTML = "Notification permission granted." 
    //console.log("Notification permission granted.");

   // get the token in the form of promise
   return messaging.getToken()
  })
  .then(function(token) {
    // print the token on the HTML page
    //TokenElem.innerHTML = "token is : " + token
         $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'/SaveNotificationToken',
        data:{token : token, _token: "<?php echo csrf_token(); ?>",UserId:             {{auth()->user()->id}} },
        success:function(data){
            //alert(data+"You will receive notiications from clients that viewed your service ");
            $("#msg").html(data);
        }
    }); 

   })
 .catch(function (err) {
  //ErrElem.innerHTML = ErrElem.innerHTML + "; " + err
   console.log("Unable to get permission to notify.", err);
});


}
```